# htmlagilitypack invalid cast exception when grabbing nodes with certain classes

Tags: exception, dom, html-agility-pack

I'm wanting to grab `div` items from an HTML page that contains certain class types.
I'm using this:

```
HtmlNode authorNode =(HtmlNode) doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Split(' ').Any(b => b.Equals("byline") && b.Equals("list-pipes")));
```

and I get this exception

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]' to type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode'.
  Source=Project1
  StackTrace:
       at Project1.Scraper.processBI_Article(String uri) in C:\Users\jgarber\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Project1\Scraper.cs:line 233
       at Project1.Scraper.processNode(String uri, HtmlNode parentNode) in C:\Users\jgarber\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Project1\Scraper.cs:line 194
       at Project1.Scraper.ExecuteScraping() in C:\Users\jgarber\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Project1\Scraper.cs:line 107
       at Project1.WebscrapingMain.Main() in C:\Users\jgarber\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Project1\WebscrapingMain.cs:line 64
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I'm confused as to what I need to do now in order to get this to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code returns an Enumerable of `HtmlNode`, not just one node (you're using .Where, which returns a all items matching). If you're only interested in the first item, use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` or if you know there to be only one item, use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` instead of just `Where`.

So:

```
 HtmlNode authorNode = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                           .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") 
                                       && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Split(' ')
                                       .Any(b => b.Equals("byline") && b.Equals("list-pipes")))
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or assign it to a Enumerable of HtmlNode:

```
 IEnumerable<HtmlNode> authorNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                           .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") 
                                       && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Split(' ')
                                       .Any(b => b.Equals("byline") && b.Equals("list-pipes")));
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  this definitely helped.  I also realized I could output the content as a `List<HtmlNode>` just in case I needed to worry about anything other nodes.  but right now I only am focusing on the first node!  Again, Thank you.